# Why is top:inherit; Behaving This Way?

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal navigation <ul>, and in one of the <li>s I have a <div> element that I was conducting some positioning experiments with.

Along the way I noticed that I could position the inner div inside of the li using

```
li div {
    position: absolute;
    top: inherit;
    left: inherit;
}
```

even though I have assigned no top or left properties to the li! Even in Firefox "Computed Styles" inspector. How exactly is it inheriting properties that don't exist? Are my browsers (newest FF & Chrome) just implicitly positioning it, or do the top: and left: properties always exist invisibly?

Also I'm guessing IE<8 will cough this back up...

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xAk97/

Comment: Of course has an inherited value .... if you don't set a value it takes the default one. In this case is `auto` change inherit for auto and you'll see is the same

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this is a perfectly valid answer. Why post as real answer?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's putting your div below the li's content. If you remove the copy "Box 3", your div is put at top:0 and left:0 of that parent li. If you give your li position of relative and put your div top:0 and left:0, it will place your div in the top left corner of your li.

Comment: Yes I see what it's doing. I am messing with bootstrap 2.3.2 dropdowns. In situations where the li's size is determined by child elements (eg a 40x100 anchor), the top:auto left:auto works really well in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any value with `inherit` the element is gonna take the same value as his parent. If you don't specify a value in your CSS the `inherited` value is the default one for that property.

In this case if top isn't defined the element will take that value as `auto`.

If you check the console in this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xAk97/6/)** you can check what property is been assigned.

Comment: Thanks! Just learned something new about absolute positioning.

Comment: @i-live-in-a-storm-drain check the fiddle I posted on the console you see auto and auto